# SPI MISO line not working

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, resistors, i2c, spi

I am using a [KSZ8463 Ethernet Switch IC](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/OTH/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/IEEE1588-Precision-Time-Protocol-Enabled-Three-Port-10-100-Managed-Switch-with-MII-or-RMII-DS00002642A.pdf).

When I connect the SPI MISO lane to another board having 2 peripherals - CPU and a CAN Controller IC - there's a spike of 0.3A current and the Switch IC stops working.

Can someone tell me what might be the reason, and if 3.6kohm pull-up are fine?

Image:

[image]

The SPI lines go to a board to board connector.

Comment: Have you checked if both chips drive their SPI data outputs simultaneously?

Comment: Let me check that also

Answer (score 1):

One classic mistake is that when you connect two live, supplied boards and the TTL level signals connect before ground pins, something else might become ground temporarily, resulting in wrong voltage potentials, which might in turn fry sensitive parts. You can prevent this by adding some series resistance like 100Ω on all signals.

3k6 should work for pull-up, though I don't see why you picked such an exotic value for. 10k or 4k7 are commonly used.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Let me check